# Embedding CSS Style, Active Hyperlink in <asp: Label>

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this code in my page

```
<div id="sidebar-menu">
                        <ul>
                             <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckData" runat="server" CssClass="" Text="Truck Data" NavigateUrl="~/View/TruckData.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black;"></i> 
                                 Truck Data</asp:HyperLink>
                                  </li>
                             <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_MaintenanceRecord" runat="server"  NavigateUrl="~/View/MaintenanceRecord.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:black"> </i>
                                     Maintenance Record</asp:HyperLink> 
                                     </li>
                             <li>
                                 <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_MaintenanceSchedule" runat="server" Text="Maintenance Schedule" NavigateUrl="~/View/MaintenanceSchedule.aspx" Font-Underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                                     <i class="glyphicon glyph  icon-calendar" style="color:black"> </i>
                                Maintenance Schedule </asp:HyperLink>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                 <asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_Inspection" runat="server" text="inspection" navigateurl="~/view/inspection.aspx" font-underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i>
                                Inspection </asp:hyperlink>
                             </li>
                            <li>
                                 <asp:hyperlink id="hyperlink_MaintenanceChecklist" runat="server" text="inspection" navigateurl="~/view/maintenancechecklist.aspx" font-underline="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: black">
                                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color:black"></i>
                                Maintenance Checklist </asp:hyperlink>
                             </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- End div #sidebar-menu -->
            </div><!-- End div .body .rows .scroll-y -->
        </div>
```

what css style would enable `active`  to be highlighted? I want to highlight the current page that I have clicked. I have this on my current `css`.

```
#sidebar-menu > ul > li > a.Link:Active{
    color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try placing the active on the li element, this way it covers the entire link:

```
#sidebar-menu > ul > li:Active{
    color: #fff;
    background: highlight;
}
```